# what does "say of" mean?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

> In staff meetings, the principal would say of teachers not meeting the benchmarks that "she's not with us; she's not on the team."

I'm stuck in understanding "say of" in that sentence. is the sentence "she's not with us; she's not on the team" the principal's remark about the teachers?
can I paraphrase it as:

> In staff meetings, the principal would say "she's not with us; she's not on the team." about teachers those who don't meet the benchmarks.

If correct, I'd like to want to know which of these two is more common and formal, and whether either one is a written expression. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your re-write conveys the message. As to which is more common I cannot say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your two sentences mean the same thing.  "Of" in "say of" is being used in its sense of "about", so you could also say

> In staff meetings, the principal would say about teachers not meeting the benchmarks that "she's not with us; she's not on the team."

"Say of" is not an idiom as such, if that's what you mean by "written expression".  As I've just explained, the words are actually being used in a perfectly standard way.  But it is such a common combination of words that people might easily *think* it was an idiom, but they'd be wrong.

By the way, you've got a stray "those" in your second sentence, it should be just "teachers who don't meet the benchmarks".  Apart from that, you've got it quite right.

Both sentences are equally correct and equally formal.  I'd prefer the first, if the aim is to draw attention to what the director said, because putting something last in a sentence makes it more noticeable, just as everyone remembers the last song of a concert.